# find text on the page and put it in a tag

Tags: jquery

I have `<div>` with text. This text contain URLs.

```
<div id="text">
 text,text, https://static01.nyt.com/images/2021/09/14/science/07CAT-STRIPES/07CAT-STRIPES-mediumSquareAt3X-v2.jpg 
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $('#text').each(function() {
        var exp = /(\b[^"'](https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    })
    
</script>
```

Question is: how to take URL and place it in `<img src="here">`?

Comment: Missing a `"` in `<div id="text>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get the URL from the text, then add it as the `src` attribute of any image.

```js
$('#text').each(function() {
  var exp = /((https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig
        
  // Find the URL in the div
  const urls = $(this).text().match(exp)
  
  // Loop through the URLs
  for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  
    // As an example, we're setting the img src that corrosponds to the
    // current index
    $('img').eq(i).attr('src', urls[i])
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">
 text,text, https://static01.nyt.com/images/2021/09/14/science/07CAT-STRIPES/07CAT-STRIPES-mediumSquareAt3X-v2.jpg, text, https://static01.nyt.com/images/2021/09/14/science/07CAT-STRIPES/07CAT-STRIPES-mediumSquareAt3X-v2.jpg 
</div>

<img>

<img>
```

Comment: If urls more than one it show only the first image

Comment: Well you didn't specify that there could be more than one URL. I can only work with what you give me.

Comment: Updated the answer to work with more than 1 URL

Answer (score -1):

Try this
https://regex101.com/r/pM2GrT/1
Regex code Code generator